# csvファイルの行数や列数の値を代入する方法

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

da_allという複数行*複数列のcsvファイル（今回は12*170）があるのですが以下のプログラムでravelで1列にした後最後に毎度手打ちでリシェイプで元の形に戻しているので手間がかかっています。12や170をda_allを用いて代入させる方法は存在するのでしょうか。

```
da_all1=np.ravel(da_all)[None,:].T
sc = StandardScaler()
data_del_stand = sc.fit_transform(da_all1)
data = scaler.transform(data_del_stand)
data = data.T.reshape(12,170)
```

Answer (score 0):

同じ形に戻すのであれば、処理前に [numpy.ndarray.shape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) で次元・要素数を取得しておいて、[numpy.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)の時にそれを指定すれば良いのでは？

```
orgshape = da_all.shape    #### shapeを取得して記録

da_all1=np.ravel(da_all)[None,:].T
sc = StandardScaler()
data_del_stand = sc.fit_transform(da_all1)
data = scaler.transform(data_del_stand)

data = data.T.reshape(orgshape)    #### reshape時に指定
```